# constructing regex to find lines not beginning with certain strings with grep in bash

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I'm trying to come up with a regex that will match all lines that dont start with

```
10[TAB]A
```

or

```
M10....
```

and work with ggrep in the bash.

Got something like this:

```
^(^(10\tA|M10*))
```

but it's obviously wrong

Help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the below grep command.

```
grep -P '^(?!10\tA|M10)' file
```

`(?!10\tA|M10)` This negative lookahead asserts that the string following the starting anchor (ie, start  of the line) won't be `10` tab A or `M10`. If a line satisfies this condition then the match would occur at the start of that corresponding line. Thus results in printing those lines.

Comment: [Accept the answer which helped you the most.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: just got 15 rep, so here u go :)

Answer (score 5):

Use `-v` option:

```
grep -v '^10\tA\|^M10' /path/to/file

grep -Ev '^10\tA|^M10' /path/to/file
```

With `-v` option, it will print non-matching lines.

---

Note: `\t` will not work. Input it as a real tab character (by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>).

Comment: Better to use `grep -E` than `egrep` as the latter is deprecated.

Comment: @TomFenech, Thank you for the information. I didn't know that it is deprecated. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Awk way

```
awk '!/^(10\tA|M10)/' file
```

or if you want to use grep

```
grep -Ev '^(10      A|M10)' file
```

Comment: your awk worked, but your grep didnt. it printed a couple of lines beginning with 10tabA... Thanks though!

Comment: Yes the grep answer depends on your tab spacing, i prefer the awk one but your question specified grep so i thought i'd add both :)